# Multi oneclick function with loop

Tags: javascript

I have multi oneclick button who start 2 function a and b, button is in foreach loop but when i click button he give only last rekord data.

How i can add correct js on php foreach loop?

```js
function a() 
{
    document.getElementById('img').src='{{$produkt->productIcon->productIconSmallUrl}}';
  
}

function b(){
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "{{$produkt->productPurchasePriceGrossLast}}" ;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="/placeholder.png" style="width:100px">
<br>Cena: <p id="price"></p>

<br>
<br>
<button onclick="a();b();">Kupuje</button>
```

Controller:

```
public function getProducts ()

{

$address = 'https://growtent.iai-shop.com/api/?gate=products/get/84/soap';
$wsdl = $address . '/wsdl';
$binding = array();
$binding['location'] = $address;
$binding['trace'] = true;
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $binding);




$request = array();
$request['get'] = array();
$request['get']['authenticate'] = array();
$request['get']['authenticate']['userLogin'] = $this->login;
$request['get']['authenticate']['authenticateKey'] = sha1(date('Ymd') . sha1($this->password));

$request['get']['params'] = array();
$request['get']['params']['returnProducts'] = "active";
$request['get']['params']['productIsAvailable'] = "y";
$request['get']['params']['resultsPage'] = 2;
$request['get']['params']['resultsLimit'] = 10;
//$request['get']['params']['categories'][0]['categoryName'] = "Growboxy";


$response = $client->__call('get', $request);


return view('welcome',['response'=>$response]);




}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@getProducts');
```

View file:

```
    <body>


<img id="img" src="/placeholder.png" style="width:100px">
<br>Cena: <p id="price"></p>


<br>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>




@foreach($response->results as $produkt)

<p>ID: {{$produkt->productId}}</p>
@foreach($produkt->productDescriptionsLangData as $name)

@if($name->langId == 'pol')
<a href="https://www.growtent.pl/product-pol-{{$produkt->productId}}"><p>{{$name->productName}}</p></a>

@endif
@endforeach
<p>{{$produkt->productPurchasePriceGrossLast}} zł</p>
<img src="{{$produkt->productIcon->productIconSmallUrl}}" />              

 <button onclick="a();b();">test</button>
 <button onclick="document.getElementById('img').src='{{$produkt->productIcon->productIconSmallUrl}}'">fota</button>


@endforeach


<script>


 function a() 
 {
          document.getElementById('img').src='{{$produkt->productIcon->productIconSmallUrl}}';

}

function b(){
   document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "{{$produkt->productPurchasePriceGrossLast}}" ;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: I add rest code

Comment: Why 2 function and not only one?, you could merge them into one

Comment: The JS functions are not in the foreach loop, hence at the client-side they contain hard-coded values for the `src` and `innerHTML`, the last values after the PHP loop.

Comment: That i think is problem thanks for answer, but how i can use js function in loop?

Answer (score 0):

You're render img and price elements as tag, with no ID, remember the ID must be unique, in case you want to access them you need to retrieve them with unique ID, so one option would be to set an ID unique and after set it the value. Something like this:

```
@foreach($response->results as $produkt)

    <p>ID: {{$produkt->productId}}</p>
    @foreach($produkt->productDescriptionsLangData as $name)
        @if($name->langId == 'pol')
        <a href="https://www.growtent.pl/product-pol-{{$produkt->productId}}">.<p>{{$name->productName}}</p></a>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    <p id="p_{{$product->id}}">{{$produkt->productPurchasePriceGrossLast}} zł</p>
    <img id="img_{{$product->id}}" src="{{$produkt->productIcon->productIconSmallUrl}}" />              

    <button onclick="a();b();">test</button>

 @endforeach

 function a() 
 {
   document.getElementById('img_{{$product->productId}}').src='{{$produkt->productIcon->productIconSmallUrl}}';
 }

 function b(){
    document.getElementById("p_{{$product->productId}}").innerHTML = "{{$produkt->productPurchasePriceGrossLast}}" ;
 }
```

Comment: It's no sens i can add single butto call: <button onclick="document.getElementById('img').src='{{$produkt->productIcon->productIconSmallUrl}}'">fota</button> and he will change image at any produt what i api call at top. I print a lot of product but button change only 1 element at top side when i click him.

Comment: It's not supposed that each image is unique for each product? if you want to set the same value to all images and p, you can add a class and retrieve the elements by this.